# Ubuntu: AMD64 vs i386?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

I can't understand what these are even though I've read articles about them.

Does it have something to do with 32 bits and 64 bits CPU? So why is it saying "AMD"64 and "i386"?

AMD is a label just like Intel? So, if I've got an Intel Core 2 Duo (MacBook Pro), then I can't use AMD64 even though Intel Core is 64 bits.

Comment: Related (on [ubuntu.se]): [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus), [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64), and [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you can use amd64 on your Intel Core 2 Duo.  The architecture is named after AMD because AMD invented it, with the Athlon 64.  Similarly, the 32-bit i386 architecture is named after Intel's 386 processor, because it was the first of its kind, but i386 will also work on AMD processors.

Comment: aways wondered about this +1