# Why is 64 bits version called AMD64 and 32 bits version called i386?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

I have never understood this.

This is what I know: You need a 64 bit OS if you want to handle more than 2 GB RAM. Else, a 32 bit OS is sufficient.

So on Ubuntu's homepage you can download either 64 bit or 32 bit versions. But the 64 bit version is called `amd64` and the 32 bit verison is called `i386`.

So I have to have an AMD processor to run `amd64` and Intel to run `i386`?

If someone codes  software (let's say Apache), does he have to code one for 32 bits and one for 64 bits? Does some software only exist for 32 bit and not 64 and vice versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu: AMD64 vs i386?](https://superuser.com/questions/128482/ubuntu-amd64-vs-i386) (as [mentioned there](https://superuser.com/a/128500/105707)) Also related (on [ubuntu.se]): [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus), [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54296/22949), and [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7034/22949)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The 64-bit version is typically called 'amd64' because AMD developed the 64-bit instruction extensions. (AMD extended the x86 architecture to 64 bits while Intel was working on Itanium, but Intel later adopted those same instructions.)

The 32-bit version is called i386, because Intel originated the 32-bit instruction set used on these chips.

You can run the 64-bit version on virtually any 64-bit capable x86 compatible chip, and the 32-bit version on any modern x86-compatible chip.

Depending on how you write your software, it may or may not need to be rewritten for 64 bits. (Generally, compiled software will need changes, but not all interpreted software -- e.g., Python or Perl -- will require changes.)

Comment: Do you say the father of 32 bit instruction is Intel and for 64 bit AMD?

Answer (score 6):

I explained the origin of the names in my response to [your similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/128482/ubuntu-amd64-vs-i386) a few minutes ago.

Comment: oh i must have had a memory leak. didnt know i posted one almost exactly before. it has been 2 long days=)

Answer (score 5):

AMD came out with the 64-bit ISA used, so it's called AMD64. Intel has their own version, EM64T, which is mostly compatible. Likewise, Intel had the 32-bit ISA first, on their i80386, or i386 for short. AMD licensed it from them long ago.